# SQL Server 2008: Row count for each hour in a Day and Row count for each day in a Month

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get row count in a given week for each day as below, which works fine

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Monday' THEN 1 END) AS M,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Tuesday' THEN 1 END) AS T,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Wednesday' THEN 1 END) AS W,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Thursday' THEN 1 END) AS R,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Friday' THEN 1 END) AS F,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [created_at]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 END) AS S,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM PARCEL
WHERE [created_at] BETWEEN '2017-03-26 00:00:00'/*Sunday, report start date*/ AND '2017-04-10 23:59:59'/* Saturday, report end date */
```

I am also trying to get row count for each hour in a given day as below

```
Hour1 Hour2 Hour3 Hour4 .............Hour24  Total
 33    544   55     77                 23    13444
```

Also row count for each day in a given month as below

```
 Day1  Day2  Day3   Day4 .............Day31  Total
 33    544   55     77                 23    13444
```

I am pretty new to sql programming, am not sure where to start on this for tha lateral 2 reports, can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into using a PIVOT table.  You can use the same solution for your hour as well as the day of week or even day in month just change a few things in the query.

Here is an example for you that gives you the Sunday, Monday, etc. table that you first asked for.  It should get you started.

```
;WITH CTE_Parcel AS
    (
    SELECT created_at
        , 1 AS ItemCount
        , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, created_at) AS DayOfOrder
        , DATEPART(HOUR, created_at) AS HourOfOrder
        , SundayOfWeek = DATEADD(DAY , 7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,created_at),created_at)
    FROM PARCEL
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-03-26 00:00:00'/*Sunday, report start date*/ AND '2017-04-10 23:59:59'/* Saturday, report end date */
    )
SELECT SundayOfWeek
    , PT.Sunday
    , PT.Monday
    , PT.Tuesday
    , PT.Wednesday
    , PT.Thursday
    , PT.Friday
    , PT.Saturday 
    , WeekTotal = PT.Sunday + PT.Monday + PT.Tuesday + PT.Wednesday + PT.Thursday + PT.Friday + PT.Saturday 
FROM (SELECT ItemCount, DayOfOrder, HourOfOrder, SundayOfWeek FROM CTE_Parcel) AS P
    PIVOT (COUNT(ItemCount) FOR DayOfOrder IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])) AS PT
ORDER BY PT.SundayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep it simple if you preagregate and then pivot your data, like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  ISNULL(CAST(part AS VARCHAR(5)), 'Total')   AS part,
                    COUNT(*)            AS part_count
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  DATEPART([HOUR], [created_at]) AS part
                        FROM    PARCEL
                        WHERE   [created_at] >= '20170326'
                                AND [created_at] < '20170327'
                    ) grp
            GROUP BY
                    GROUPING SETS((part),())
        ) pre
PIVOT   (MAX(part_count) FOR part IN (
            [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],
            [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],
            [17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23], Total)) pvt;
```

The derived table has the same structure for your three scenarios, you just have to change the requested datepart and date range predicate.
After that adjust the allowed values for a week(1-7), day(0-23) or month (1-31) in the PIVOT clause and acordingly the column names in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a table just to show you the job:

```
create table PARCEL(created_at datetime);

DECLARE @start datetime, @end datetime;

SET @start = '20170101';
SET @end = '20170131';

--= generates a series of dates
;WITH genDate AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1) 
             n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects
)
INSERT INTO PARCEL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start)
FROM genDate;
```

Now a simple PIVOT using a CTE function:

```
--= get count of day of week
WITH pvtDays AS
(
    SELECT DATENAME(dw, created_at) AS WkDayName,
           DATEPART(dw, created_at) AS WkDay
    FROM   PARCEL
    WHERE [created_at] BETWEEN @start AND @end
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvtDays) [Count of days], *
FROM pvtDays
PIVOT (COUNT(WkDay) FOR WkDayName IN(Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday)) pvt
;

| Count of days | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
|---------------|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|----------|
| 31            | 5      | 5      | 5       | 4         | 4        | 4      | 4        |
```

Next step, I've created a table just to simulate 12 hours at day:

```
--= We need to generates on record for each hour of the day
create table HoursDay (h int);
insert into HoursDay values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11);
```

And PIVOT again using hours of day:

```
--= get count of hours at day
WITH pvtHours AS
(
    SELECT     HoursDay.h
    FROM       PARCEL
    CROSS JOIN HoursDay
    WHERE [created_at] BETWEEN @start AND @end
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvtHours) [Hours at day], *
FROM pvtHours
PIVOT (COUNT(h) FOR h IN([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11])) pvt
;

| Hours at day | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
|--------------|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
| 372          | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 | 31 |
```

*Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/FPIP1175)*